# Wait until element has sibling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm iterating through a lazy loading list in Selenium Python.

The list is lazy loaded so selenium should wait until the current element has a sibling.

I tried it with:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((current_element.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following-sibling::*'))))
```

I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
```

Poorly I can't find a way how this could work.
How could this be achieved?

Comment: different pages may have different problems. Without real URL we can't test what is the real problem and we can only suggest to use longer `timeout` - but it may not work if page has different problem (ie. it may need to click some element, or it may need to scroll page to load data, etc)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. @furas
I think the problem is pretty clear and the url is not needed. You could think of any list which is endless lazy loaded.
I solved it now, but I think there could be a better solution. The solution below works for every url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is the best solution but it works:

```
next_element = ""

while next_element == "":
    try:
        next_element = current_element.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following-sibling::*')
    except:
        next_element = ""
```